# structuredClone is not a function - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, json

Currently working with arrays of objects of arrays of objects and filtering those lists to generate new lists, but do not want to mutate the original list.

To do this, I clone the data, and in plain javascript I easily accomplish this with `structedClone()`. See JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhekqx2a/

```js
 const items = [
     {"name": "one", list: [{'name': 'listItemOne'}]},
     {"name": "two", list: [{'name': 'listItemOne'}]},
 ];
  
 //DEEP CLONE
 const itemsDeepClone = structuredClone(items);
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

However, when I attempt to use this in an LWC, I get the following error:

> [structuredClone is not a function]

Can someone explain what it is about LWC that makes this function not available? Is it due to lightning locker service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for future reference, you can verify what api's are supported using the
[Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

[image]

as you can see, this is not supported yet.

Comment: is there any workaround? how can we call browser `structuredClone` function?

Comment: if you need to deepclone you can workaround with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));